# How to test a trained model using tensorflow for image classification

Tags: tensorflow

I created a simple image classification network using tensor flow and trained it successfully. But while testing the model with same input image I am getting different prediction results. Details are given below

Only two classes (namely dog and cat) are present in the dataset. Converted the dataset to tfrecord before using them. The network architecture is shown below.

```
def conv_layer(input, channels_in, fileter_size,channels_out,name="conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([fileter_size,fileter_size,channels_in,channels_out],stddev =0.1),name = name + "/W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape= [channels_out]),name= name +"/B")
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input,w,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding = "SAME")
        ret = tf.nn.max_pool( (conv + b),ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1],padding = "SAME")
    return(ret) 

def fc_layer(input,channels_in,channels_out,name = "fc"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([channels_in,channels_out],stddev =0.1),name = name +"/W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape= [channels_out]),name= name +"/B")
        mul = tf.matmul(input,w)
        ret = tf.add(mul,b, name = "logits")
    return(ret)

def inference(image_batch):
    fc1_size = 128
    num_classes = 2
    conv1 = conv_layer(image_batch,3,3,32,"conv1")
    conv2 = conv_layer(conv1,32,3,32,"conv2")
    conv3 = conv_layer(conv2,32,3,64,"conv3")
    shape = conv3.get_shape()
    #shape = tf.shape(conv3)
    flat = tf.reshape(conv3,shape = [-1,shape[1:4].num_elements()])
    fc1 = fc_layer(flat,shape[1:4].num_elements(),fc1_size,"fc1")
    logits = fc_layer(fc1,fc1_size,num_classes,"fc2")
    return(logits)
```

Training of model is done by following code

```
label, image = ReadData.read_and_decode_single_example(["trian.tfrecords"],2,128*128*3)
label = tf.argmax(label)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
# groups examples into batches randomly
image = tf.reshape(image,shape = [128,128,3])
image = tf.multiply(image,1.0/255,name = "in_image")#np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
image_batch_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [None,128,128,3],name = "image_batch_ph")
label_batch_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape = [None],name = "label_batch_ph")
images_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image, label], batch_size=32,
    capacity=2000,
    min_after_dequeue=1000,name = "shuffle_step")
predict = inference(image_batch_ph)
y_pred = tf.nn.softmax(predict,name='y_pred')
loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( labels = label_batch_ph,logits = predict)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(loss)

loss_mean = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predict,1),label_batch_ph)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32)) 

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(init)

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

i = 0

while i < 10000:
    #labels = sess.run(labels_batch)    
    #print labels
    imgs,lbs = sess.run([images_batch,labels_batch])
    _,lossMean = sess.run([train_op,loss_mean],feed_dict={image_batch_ph:imgs,label_batch_ph:lbs})
         if i % 1000 == 0:
              print "iteration  ",i,"Loss   :",lossMean    
         if i%2000 == 0:
              acc = sess.run([accuracy],feed_dict={image_batch_ph:imgs,label_batch_ph:lbs})
              print "iteration  ",i,"accuracy   :",acc
    i += 1
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./model/model.ckpt")
print( "model is saved at %s",save_path)
```

*"ReadData.read_and_decode_single_example()" function return a single image tensor and corresponding label tensor. The current session (trained model) is saved in the folder ./model*

For testing, I wrote another script shown below. My intention is to load the session saved by above script and use the model to classify an image.

```
import cv2
image_size = 128 
image = cv2.imread("./dog.11.jpg")
image = cv2.resize(image, (image_size, image_size),0,0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = tf.reshape(image,shape = [128,128,3])
image = tf.multiply(image,1.0/255,name = "in_image")#np.multiply(image, 1.0 / 255.0)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./model/model.ckpt.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./model/'))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init) 
image_batch_ph = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("image_batch_ph:0")
test_image = sess.run(image) 
y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("y_pred:0")

predicted_labels = sess.run(y_pred,feed_dict={image_batch_ph:test_image})

print predicted_labels
```

While testing the model with same image multiple time prediction results are different. I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Mistake was mine. While using a pre-trained model from check point you don't need

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

This will initialize the weights with random new values.